# Does userfaultfd now support file backed map?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I saw from the documentation of userfaultfd

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/userfaultfd.2.en.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_userfaultfd.2.html

that userfaultfd will start supporting shared map since kernel 4.11. However, the documentation still looks very ambiguous in the sense that I'm still wondering will these include supporting file-backed mmap (which can also be MAP_SHARED)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer definitively, since the information is not in the manual page(s), we can see the source.

Attempting to register a userfaultfd object with an address range must [check](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3.8/source/fs/userfaultfd.c#L1376) whether that range is "compatible":

```
…
/* check not compatible vmas */
ret = -EINVAL;
if (!vma_can_userfault(cur))
    goto out_unlock;
```

and the [definition of compatibility](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3.8/source/include/linux/userfaultfd_k.h#L146) is:

```
if ((vm_flags & VM_UFFD_MINOR) &&
    (!is_vm_hugetlb_page(vma) && !vma_is_shmem(vma)))
    return false;
#ifndef CONFIG_PTE_MARKER_UFFD_WP
/*
 * If user requested uffd-wp but not enabled pte markers for
 * uffd-wp, then shmem & hugetlbfs are not supported but only
 * anonymous.
 */
if ((vm_flags & VM_UFFD_WP) && !vma_is_anonymous(vma))
    return false;
#endif
return vma_is_anonymous(vma) || is_vm_hugetlb_page(vma) ||
    vma_is_shmem(vma);
```

Thus, anonymous mappings or mappings in:

- [tmpfs-backed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b0506e488da5cf2f07f3a4f6d7acaa8f459ad714), aka shared memory virtual filesystem (tmpfs, `shmget`) mappings are compatible
- when CONFIG_SHMEM is disabled, file-backed ranges which have been remapped (with `generic_file_mmap`) as shared are also compatible

The meaning of `VM_UFFD_MINOR` is support for notifications on minor page faults.